# Как скопировать все public synonym, роли и права пользователя Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть БД, созданная с помощью утилит экспорта/импорта. При импорте не скопировались права и роли, а так же публичные синонимы. Как перетащить потерявшиеся права, роли и синонимы, если в наличии есть `sqlplus` и между базами прокинут `database link` ?

Comment: Можно с dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl, например для прав, для других объектов  в пакете есть также подходящие функции. Можно запросом из словарей генерировать ddl. А почему не всё перенеслось?

Comment: Переносил не я. Сдается мне, что просто забыли импортировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате были написаны sql запросы, которые копировали команды выдачи грантов на основе сравнения словаря данных.
Для выдачи прав использовались следующие таблицы:

- *dba_tab_privs*  - все пользователи и их полномочия, а так же кто выдал эти полномочия
- *dba_role_privs* - роли предоставленные пользователям и другим ролям
- *dba_roles*  - список ролей
- *dba_sys_privs* - системные привилегии

Для синонимов использовал таблицу *dba_synonyms*

Comment: А sys_privs не пропали?

Comment: А я на них даже не посмотрел. Спасибо!